# Kotlin Instrumented Android Test with real views and real navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-espresso

In my Java Android project I have following Espresso tests:

```
@Test
public void whenButtonClick_thenNextFragmentVisible() {
    onView(withId(R.id.menu_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.menu_button)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.next_menu_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.next_menu_button)).perform(click());
    // ...
}
```

I am testing moving through the app and test some navigation between fragments.

In a new app I am now using Kotlin and the Navigation component. The only way I found to test navigation is:

```
@Test
fun whenButtonClick_thenNavigatedToNextFragment() {
    val navController = TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())

    val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<MenuFragment>(themeResId = R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents)
    scenario.onFragment { fragment ->
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.navigation_graph)
        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
    }
    onView(withId(R.id.menu_button)).perform(click())
    Assert.assertEquals(navController.currentDestination?.id, R.id.nextFragment)
    // I can't test something like onView(withId(R.id.next_menu_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed())) here
}
```

For me in the first case it looks to me like the navigation is really done and it is like a user does the navigation. But in the second case it seems to me that the navigation is only theoretically done but the target of the navigation is not really visible. This would mean I can only test one navigation and I have to hope that if `navController.currentDestination` is `R.id.nextFragment` that all necessary views are visible and in the state I assume without being able to explicitly test it.

Is it possible to test *real* navigation with *real* views in Kotlin with the Navigation component?